# Get week in array of days

Tags: javascript

I have a array of days:

```
var days = [1,5,7,9,12,16,23,27,45,66];
```

Now I want to find out which days belong to which week. i.e.

```
Week 1: 1,5,7
Week 2: 9,12
Week 3: 23,27
```

and so on.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: where does the week start?

Comment: `weekNumber = Math.ceil(day / 7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deceze's comment was what I was looking for, thank you.

```
var days = [1, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 23, 27, 45, 66];
var weekNumber;

for (i= 0; i <= days.length; i++) {
 weekNumber = Math.ceil(days[i] / 7);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the week with a division by `7` and round up the value to the next integer value.

```js
var days = [1, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 23, 27, 45, 66],
    weeks = {};
    
days.forEach(function (d) {
    var w = Math.ceil(d / 7);
    weeks[w] = weeks[w] || [];
    weeks[w].push(d);
});

console.log(weeks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```